# SQL select columns from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I will dive straight in with my tabels and it is quickly obvious my question

Table 1:

```
Owner    ownerID    Name    Address    userID
______________________________________________
Name        1       Tim    "top road"    1
```

Table 2:

```
User      userID    userName    password    secretQA1    secretQA2
___________________________________________________________________
            1        BigTim       pwhat         7           8
```

Table 3:

```
secretQA  id    question       answer
_______________________________________
          7     "Mums name"     "Tony"
          8     "Fav sport"     "dressing up"
```

Anyway what I want to do is I know the ownerID is 1 and I want to give the owner all his information! So what I had been doing is something like this:

```
SELECT secretQA.question AS Question1, secretQA.answer AS Answer1,
secretQA.question AS Question2, secretQA.answer AS Answer2,
User.password AS Password
FROM secretQA, owner, User
WHERE owner.id = 1
AND SecretQA.id = owner.secretQA1
AND SecretQA.id = owner.secretQA2
AND user.id = owner.userID;
```

But to no avail!

This is what I want to obtain:

```
Question1    Answer1    Question2    Answer2        Password
____________________________________________________________
"Mums name"   "Tony"    "Fav sport"  "dressing up"  pwhat
```

Cheers for all future help

EDIT: Password is just an example here and would not be plain text in my real version this is just a simplified question of what I am doing

Comment: Do you know, in advance, how many secret questions there are?

Comment: Are you storing your password in plaintext? These tables are not normalized. It is also better practice to move away from implicit table joins.

Comment: **WHERE owner.id = 1** should be **WHERE owner.OwnerID = 1**, as the former isn't a valid field name.

Comment: Thier would be two secret questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want you have to join twice to the SecretQA table.  This is an example of why it's better to use explicit join syntax.

This should work

```
     SELECT q1.question AS Question1, 
            q1.answer AS Answer1,
            q2.question AS Question2,
            q2.answer AS Answer2,
            u.password AS Password
       FROM User u
       JOIN owner o ON u.id = o.userID
  LEFT JOIN secretQA q1 on o.secretQA1 = q1.id
  LEFT JOIN secretQA q2 on o.secretQA2 = q2.id
      WHERE owner.id = 1
```

Notice that your `secretQA` table has to participate twice in the join.  I've given it the aliases `q1` and `q2` to make this work.

Oh, and like others have said, if you're storing passwords as plain text, tee hee. The intertubz will pwn u, srsly.

Comment: I was adding password to add to it. In actaullity it will be different

Answer (score 0):

In Table2, eliminate the 'secret1' and 'secret2' columns.  In Table3, add a new column 'userID'.

After that, you should be able to do something like

```
select u.username, u.password, s.question, s.answer
from table1 as o join table2 as u on o.userid = u.userid
join table3 as s on s.userid = o.userid
where o.ownerid = 1
```

Also, as others have noted, storing passwords as plain text is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT q1.question, q1.answer, q2.question, q2.answer, u.password
   FROM user u
   JOIN secretqa q1 ON u.secretQA1 = q1.id
   JOIN secretqa q2 ON u.secretQA2 = q2.id
  WHERE u.id = ?
```